# swift - Sign in With Apple "Sign Up not completed" error

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

Made all the setup for sign in with apple, but when pressing on continue and passing Face ID check I am getting "Sign Up not completed" error. However, no error is thrown to the delegate.

Then I tried to create a test project with my friend's Paid developer account and everything was fine, no errors. I haven't connected to the API, just trying to print Email and Fullname.

May be something is wrong with my company's Developer account?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Also having this issue! Did you get any updates?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I did followings and it was working fine.

1. Go to developer apple and choose app's bundle id
2. Remove Sign In With Apple and save
3. Again go to your app's bundle id and add Sign In With Apple and save.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this error and the root problem turned out to be some back-end data problem with my Apple account.

I ultimately had to raise an Apple Technical Support Request, generate some debug information for them, and then they ultimately fixed their back-end data for my account. The overall process took just under three weeks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]For me the reason was , I was using my bundle id in the place where **Apple services ID** should be entered in cognito user pool.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it just takes 2 days on Apple's side to process everything.
Spare yourself the hassle and just wait it out. If you have followed their documentation you did everything right:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.0/#/dev50571b902

Just go to your project's signing capabilities, click + and add Sign in with Apple:

[image]

Add the SignInWithApple Button:

```
import AuthenticationServices

...

  SignInWithAppleButton(.signUp) { request in
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
  } onCompletion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let authResults):
      handleSuccess(authorization: authResults)
    case .failure(let error):
      logger.error("SIWA login failure: \(error)")
    }
  }
  .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had created Auth Key with Apple Sign selected in which is never used. When I remove the unused Auth Key it worked.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here. What is the Auth Key?

Comment: I am facing the same issue so not sure about auth key!! can you specify what that is?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591729/swift-sign-in-with-apple-always-results-in-sign-up-not-completed-after-the-f), this is sometimes an issue one Apple's end. I have tested with Apple's [own project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple) from the documentation and ran into the same issue.

I reached out to Apple DTS support and they replied the following:

> The underlying issue was unexpected. We have confirmed the issue was
> caused by an internal data feed sync operation and was resolved today.

So in my case, the issue went away after 2 days without any changes.