# Swift - Sign in with apple always results in 'Sign up not completed' after the facial recognition runs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, apple-sign-in

I started out by following this tutorial to set up 'Sign in with apple' using Firebase:

https://medium.com/swift-productions/sign-in-with-apple-with-firebase-authentication-xcode-12-swift-5-3-7f5ee7902ea3

However, even when I follow this tutorial:

https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/sign-in-with-apple-swift#comment-37591

Without any reference to Firebase, I can't get past 'Sign up not completed' in the apple Sign in modal, after the facial recognition 'Signing in' spinner runs.

I've added the capability in XCode & in the identifier, tried adding the Key and without the Key as some tutorials don't mention it. I can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Code taken from tutorials above:

```
import UIKit
import AuthenticationServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAppleButton()
    }
    
    func setupAppleButton() {
            view.addSubview(appleButton)
            appleButton.cornerRadius = 12
            appleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAppleIdRequest), for: .touchUpInside)
            appleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            appleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            appleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 235).isActive = true
            appleButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            appleButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -70).isActive = true
        }
    
    @objc func handleAppleIdRequest() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as?  ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
            let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
            let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName
            let email = appleIDCredential.email
            print("User id is \(userIdentifier) \n Full Name is \(String(describing: fullName)) \n Email id is \(String(describing: email))")
        }
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle error.
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Same, tried with a blank project and still got this error, is this an issue Apple side ?

Comment: Yes, it's working today and I didn't change anything!

Comment: I can confirm the issue went away after 2 days with no changes for me too. I reached out to Apple Dev Support and they replied that: "The underlying issue was unexpected. We have confirmed the issue was caused by an internal data feed sync operation and was resolved today."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue Apple-side, I tried everything yesterday it didn't work and now it's working today. :)

Comment: Wow, spent 2 days on this! Code above is working fine today.

Comment: Haha yea me and my friend did the same... 2 days thinking about quitting programming 